# openai запоминание предыдущих ответов

Tags: python, telebot, chatgpt-api

недавно начал писать тг бота с интеграцией туда chatgpt, и возникли некоторые проблемы. Во первых, бот не запоминает прошлые вопросы и ответы пользователю, и каждый раз отвечает заново. Например:

- User: Сколько лет Илону Маску?
- ChatGPT: Илону Маску 50 лет. Он родился 28 июня 1971 года.
- User: Какого он роста?
- ChatGPT: Извините, я не знаю, о ком или о чем вы говорите. Вам нужно
  указать объект или человека, о котором вы хотите узнать рост.

Также бот иногда очень долго отвечает, скорее всего это связано с тем, что он отправляет конечный ответ только после генерации всего текста ответа. Можно ли это как-то исправить?

```
import telebot
from openai import OpenAI
from telebot import types

token = 'bot_token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bt1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Текстовая модель (GPT 3.5)', callback_data='bt1')
    bt2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Графическая модель (В разработке⚙)', callback_data='bt2')
    bt3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Голосовая модель (В разработке⚙)', callback_data='bt3')
    markup.add(bt3, bt2, bt1)
    start = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Я бот *****. Выбери желаемое действие:', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'bt1':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Привет! Я - текстовая модель, готовая ответить на любой твой вопрос.\nСкорее пиши мне!')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def answ(message):
    global cnt
    cnt = message.text
    result = generate()
    print(result)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)

def generate():
    generated_content = ""
    messages = [
        {"role": "user", "content": cnt}
    ]

    client = OpenAI(api_key='api_key')

    stream = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=messages,
        stream=True,
    )



    for chunk in stream:
        if chunk.choices[0].delta.content is not None:
            generated_content += chunk.choices[0].delta.content
    return generated_content

bot.infinity_polling()
```